# Which vessels in the Star Trek universe have beaten a Galaxy Class starship in one-on-one combat?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, space-combat

The Borg Cube ship is obviously one such ship that has beaten a Galaxy class in single combat.

Another is the [Tamarian cruiser](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tamarian_deep_space_cruiser), TNG 5x02 'Darmok'.

Also, the [Husnock Warship](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Delta_Rana_warship) (recreated) beat a Galaxy Class.

Has any other starship beaten a Galaxy Class in a one-on-one battle?

Comment: The Husnock warship probably should not count. There is no way to tell it's actual capabilities.

Comment: @Xantec I know, I thought about the ramifications of citing the Husnock Warship as an example. Some argue that it was just a fabrication of Kevin's. He obviously recreated it but I believe that it was an accurate recreation. According to the account of the Husnock attack on the planet, it was large enough that it could be seen by the naked eye as it orbited and that single ship had the firepower to pulverize the planet.

Comment: Technically the Duras sisters defeated the Enterprise in a Bird of Prey, but it wasn't exactly a fair fight. Also, the Romulans disabled the engines on the Enterprise in Tin Man, but that was a sneak attack. Although the ship seemed to always be on the verge of destruction, I'm having trouble thinking of many straight up fights. Even the Jem'Hadar rammed the Odyssey to take it out.

Comment: I don't suppose you want to count Tin Man.

Comment: @KyleJones Ooooh, Ooooh, good one. That was a straight up display of 'swat the fly'.

Comment: A Jem Hadar ship destroyed a Galaxy-class in DS9 - the sister ship of the Enterprise. However, I think it may have been a kamikaze attack. (I only remember this because it was referenced on TVTropes.)

Comment: Yes, that was the Odyssey. It got rammed during a 3 on 3 battle by a Jem'Hadar attack fighter.

Comment: I was going to mention the *Scimitar* from *Nemesis* for beating the Enterprise E and two Romulan Warbirds in the same engagement. But it turns out the E was Sovereign class.

Comment: @Dacio I haven't seen Nemesis but that Scimitar looks very formidable.

Comment: Nemesis is a decent flick. Not the strongest TNG film, but definitely worth watching if you feel like getting your Picard and Data on.

Comment: I don't recall that happening but: The Scimitar has the Enterprise on the run. Only combined forces and a telepath can save it. That's the Enterprise E of the Sovereign-Class thou, but we can assume that the Enterprise D wouldn't do better against the Scimitar.

Comment: @Dacio From what I'm learning, the consensus is that the Sovereign class is markedly tougher all around in a fight than the Galaxy class, and the Scimitar beat them soundly. The Scimitar may be the baddest ship out there... and they cheat... firing while cloaked.

Comment: @Einer That's one way to look at it. Another perspective is that the Scimitar could have easily destroyed the Enterprise E, nearly as easily as it destroyed the first Warbird. Except that Shinzon is held back by a combination of "I can't kill you; I need you to live", "I can swat you like a fly, so let's keep it interesting" and Evil Gloating.

Comment: So a Borg Cube, Tamarian Cruiser, Husnock Warship(*), Gomtuu (Tin Man), Klingon Bird of Prey(*), Jem'Hadar Attack Fighter(*), and the Romulan 'Scimitar'(Sovereign Class) have all beaten a Galaxy Class or better. (*)=special circumstances. Someone needs to compile this into a good answer form. Add any others that can be noted.

Comment: What about that semi-borg ship in Descent that those rouge Borg used - didn't that disable the Enterprise-D substantially, forcing it to use experimental metaphasic shielding to seek shelter in the sun (speculation, but very likely that the D would have been beaten if I recall correctly)

Comment: @N.Soong -I haven't seen that episode but if they spanked the Enterprise, it should be included.

Answer (score 4):

I can't take credit for the complete answer here as it was developed by several worthy researchers, the results of which are collected below:

The following starships have beaten a galaxy class 'or better' Federation starship in 'mostly' 1 on 1 battle.

- [Borg Cube](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q_Who_(episode))
- [Tamarian cruiser](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tamarian_deep_space_cruiser), TNG 5x02 'Darmok'.
- [Husnock Warship](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Delta_Rana_warship). Some argue that it was just a fabrication of Kevin Uxbridge. He obviously recreated it but I believe that it was an accurate recreation. Large enough to be seen by the naked eye as it orbited and with enough firepower to pulverize a planet.
- [Jem'Hadar](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Odyssey) rammed the Odyssey (kamikaze attack at end of 3 on 3 battle) – credit Xantec
- [Tin Man/Gomtuu](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tin_Man_(episode)). –  credit Kyle Jones
- [Romulan Scimitar](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis) from 'Nemesis' beat the Enterprise E (Sovereign class) and two Romulan Warbirds at the same time. –  credit Dacio

This seems to be a complete list of those ships but I seem to remember there could be one or two more that fit the criteria. The research proceeds...

Comment: ... if you can't take credit, why don't you make it community wiki, so that you won't take credit?

Comment: Also D'deridex class warbirds seem to be superior to galaxy class as a warship. But I don't remember any direct confrontation between them.

Answer (score -2):

(Late answer) :), imo aside from Borg Cube, almost all those instances where a galaxy class was "supposedly" beaten is because there was almost no shields up on that moment of attack either because enemy ship was cloaked or the weapon configuration was unknown to the federation standard (Jem Hadar : used phased polaron beams) 
...but the point here is any ship without shield can easily be destroyed or beaten regardless whether its a galaxy class or a bird of prey, but if you are going to be hypothetical on a scenario where both are shielded and properly configured it all comes down to shield strength and regenerative capabilities and its hull strength, and since a galaxy class or any large ship has both of the qualities it will outlast a cloak capable warship like the BOP and the klingon warbird.

Setting aside Federation Standard Configurations, i'd place my bet on the Modified Voyager thanks to Seven Of Nine / One / Future Janeway for enhancing and augmenting Adaptive Shield and Anti-Borg Armor :) could probably beat any of the enemy ships mentioned

Comment: Hi AltOa. Thanks for contributing. We are really looking for complete, detailed, answers and this one doesn't contain enough detail to be a good answer. Speculation and 'I'd place my bet' type answers are off limits. Please do read around, and have fun contributing/ Thanks.